# pluck on multiple joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have this data model

House `has_many :floors` (attributes => name, size, city)
Floor `has_many :rooms, belongs_to :house` (attributes => name, rooms_count)
Room `has_many :furnitures, belongs_to :floor` (attributes => name, size)
Furniture `belongs_to :room` (attributes => name, size, color)

and I want to query that way

`House.where(city: 'Paris').joins(floors: {rooms: :furnitures}).pluck(name, floors.id, floors.name, rooms.name, furnitures.name)`

This is the SQL request I want to have :

`=> SELECT houses.name, floors.id, floors.name, rooms.id, rooms.name, furnitures.id, furnitures.name FROM "houses" INNER JOIN "floors" ON "floors"."company_id" = "houses"."id" INNER JOIN "rooms" ON "rooms"."building_id" = "floors"."id" INNER JOIN "furnitures" ON "furnitures"."floor_id" = "rooms"."id" WHERE "houses"."name" = $1 [["city", "Paris"]]`

Now I get the results raw in a big array of arrays, and I want to sort it like this, but I'm quite stuck :

`[
  {
    name: 'toto',
    floors: [
      {
        id: '123',
        name: 'tata'
        rooms: [
          {
            name: 'titi',
            furnitures: [
              {
                name: 'table'
              },
              {
                name: 'chair'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]`

I need to avoid N+1 request and only refuse to have a select *.
The `pluck_to_hash` gem could be helpful but does not work very well with multi tables queries.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: `pluck('table1.column1, table1.column2, table2.column1, table2.column2')`

Comment: Table name can be hardcoded OR from `Model.table_name` OR from Arel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [deep_pluck](https://github.com/khiav223577/deep_pluck) to pluck nested associations.

```
House.where(city: 'Paris').deep_pluck(
  :name, 
  floors: [
    :id, 
    :name, 
    rooms: [
      :name,
      furnitures: :name,
    ]
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 4):

As you said you can get the results you want as an array with pluck

```
arrays = House.where(city: 'Paris').joins(floors: {rooms: :furnitures}).pluck('name', 'floors.id', 'floors.name', 'rooms.name', 'furnitures.name')
```

To get them an a hash I think you'll need to do the grouping manually. Something like the following.

```
arrays = [
  ['toto', 123, 'tata', 'titi', 'table'], 
  ['toto', 123, 'tata', 'titi', 'chair'],
  ['bob', 124, 'sue', 'hall', 'table'],
  ['bob', 124, 'sue', 'foyer', 'table']
]

arrays.inject([]) do |results, row|
  name, floor_id, floor_name, room_name, furniture_name = row

  house = results.detect{|o| o[:name] == name} || {name: name, floors: []}
  results |= [house]

  floor = house[:floors].detect{|o| o[:id] == floor_id} || {id: floor_id, name: floor_name, rooms: []}
  house[:floors] |= [floor]

  room = floor[:rooms].detect{|o| o[:name] == room_name} || {name: room_name, furnitures: []}
  floor[:rooms] |= [room]

  furniture = room[:furnitures].detect{|o| o[:name] == furniture_name} || {name: furniture_name}
  room[:furnitures] |= [furniture]

  results
end
```

Would get you something like

```
---
- :name: toto   
  :floors:
  - :id: 123
    :name: tata
    :rooms:
    - :name: titi
      :furnitures:
      - :name: table
      - :name: chair
- :name: bob   
  :floors:
  - :id: 124
    :name: sue
    :rooms:
    - :name: hall
      :furnitures:
      - :name: table
    - :name: foyer
      :furnitures:
      - :name: table
```